# Objects initialized in constructors are not collected by GC in the same way that objects initialized in methods?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

My example is using unmanaged code in managed code.

If I instantiate a class-level field in a method, the GC will collect this field before the instance of my class are being collected, like this:

```
public class SpyAgent
{
   public delegate int WindowProcedureDelegate(int Wnd, uint Msg, int WParam, int LParam);

   private WindowProcedureDelegate _windowProcedure;

   public void SpyAgent()
   {
   }

   ...

   public void SomeRandomMethod()
   {
      ...

      //GC will collect this instance before SpyAgent dispose.
      _windowProcedure = new WindowProcedureDelegate(WindowProcedure);

      SetWindowLong(window.Handle, (IntPtr)_windowProcedureIndex, _windowProcedure);
   }

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIndex, WindowProcedureDelegate newProc);

   ...
}
```

After a minute using the system, i got the following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' has detected
>   a problem in
>   'C:\Acaz\Supervise.Bootstrap\Supervise.Bootstrap\Supervise.Bootstrap\Supervise.Bootstrap\Contoso\bin\Debug\Contoso.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type
>   'Supervise.Application!Supervise.Application.SpyAgent+WindowProcedureDelegate::Invoke'.
>   This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When
>   passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the
>   managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be
>   called.

But when I instantiate the delegate in constructor, i don't got more errors.

```
public class SpyAgent
{
   public delegate int WindowProcedureDelegate(int Wnd, uint Msg, int WParam, int LParam);

   private WindowProcedureDelegate _windowProcedure;

   public void SpyAgent()
   {
      //This instance will be collected by GC just when SpyAgent start to being collected too.
      _windowProcedure = new WindowProcedureDelegate(WindowProcedure);
   }

   ...

   public void SomeRandomMethod()
   {
      ...

      SetWindowLong(window.Handle, (IntPtr)_windowProcedureIndex, _windowProcedure);
   }

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr nIndex, WindowProcedureDelegate newProc);

   ...
}
```

Why this behaviour? Why a field that is class-level initialized in a method is collected before of the class being collected. Don't make sense, because the field is declared in a class-level and can be used for the entire class. I'm storing a reference in a class-level item.

Why when I initialize the field in the constructor, the field is not collected until the class start to being collected too?

What's the difference of behaviour of Garbage Collector with objects initialized in methods and constructors?

Comment: You need to tell us how you have verified that what you describe really happens as that is not what *should* happen. I think it's more likely that you have a different bug/problem that makes you think this is the case. Please tell us what you did to verify this. If possible, could you create a small but complete program that can be compiled and run to verify this?

Comment: To make it clear, there is no difference. Assuming you called the method that instantiated the object and stored it into the field, it should have the exact same lifetime as the other example that allocated and assigned it in the constructor.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question to a more complete question.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you construct the object as well? ie. SpyAgent.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen there's nothing there. I modify the code a little to show the example. Here, SpyAgent is static. I just call SpyAgent.RandomMethod(); The constructor here is static, but makes no difference.

Comment: Well, the problem is not that the object is garbage collected too soon, since, again, there is no difference storing a reference into a field from a method compared to a constructor. Once the reference is in the field, the lifetime is the same in both cases. I think it is much more likely that there is a problem with the way you give it to the Win32 function. Perhaps .NET is not wrapping it properly? Or perhaps the specified thing you're trying to do cannot be done from C#?

Comment: And just for the future, you should never actually modify the code before posting here, at least not without just minimizing the code to make a short and complete example. You risk introducing different problems in the code than the ones you have.

Comment: I assume the field is static too?

Comment: OK, try debugging then, when it crashes, check if the field still has a value.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I checked it. Is null!

Comment: Well then something assigned null to it.

Comment: I have to check it in a more depth way. I don't have time to verify this now, but I'll in future. Thank you!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I discover the problem. Is because I call SomeRandomMethod more than one time. And everytime i do a new delegate  attribuition to the field I lost the past reference. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.

Is because I call SomeRandom Method more than one time. And everytime I do a new delegate attribution to the field, I lost the past reference and then the GC collect this past instance because is not referenced nowhere. :)

Answer (score 4):

The code snippets appear to be a very poor match with the real code you are having trouble with.  But the core issue is that native code has a dependency on the delegate object.  The garbage collector can *not* see that dependency, it doesn't know anything about GetWindowLong().  Which makes it very likely to collect the delegate object too soon, most typically during the next collection.  That's going to cause a hard crash when Windows delivers the message, when you run from the debugger then the Managed Debugger Assistant tells you about it before it produces a loud undiagnosable bang.

As is typical with the .NET Framework, you should not write this code yourself.  Subclassing a window is a very common need, Winforms and WPF need to do this as well.  Instead of spinning your own from scatch, derive your own class from the [NativeWindow class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Override the `WndProc()` method to implement your own message processing.  Call its `AssignHandle()` method when you're ready to subclass the window.  And call `ReleaseHandle()` in your WndProc override when you see the WM_NCDESTROY message, the last message that's sent to a window before it expires.  NativeWindow takes care of the delegate plumbing.  For example:

```
class SpyAgent : NativeWindow {
    public SpyWindow(IntPtr hWnd) {
        this.AssignHandle(hWnd);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 130) this.ReleaseHandle();
        // Your code here
        //...
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control of the application that will be subclassed.

Comment: That's irrelevant, you only need an IntPtr, the one you pass to the constructor.  Of course you already have one since you are calling SetWindowLong().

Comment: I have to control all the window in the mainWindow, if take the mainWindowHandle, create a instance of my native, assign handle, find all child of that window and do the same, creating my native window object and assign handle. you think is ok to do that?

Comment: You'll need to click the Ask Question button again to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees about the order in which finalizers are called.  Both your objects because unrooted and eligible for garbage collection at the same time.  You should read about the GC concept of "resurrection", in which an object which was not rooted but was still reachable from the finalizer queue gets rooted once again (by giving its reference to a rooted object).

In practice, construction order and memory order *may* affect finalization order, but this is not documented.  Do not rely on it, because it can change between .NET versions.